# CdkDragDrop unit testing events

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, coded-ui-tests

So, i've been working on unit testing for my Angular app. I'm using Angular Material and i have a component which uses the drag-drop CDK [cdk drag-drop API](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).

the html code looks like this

```
<mat-card class="interventionCard">
  <div  cdkDropListGroup class="container">
    <div cdkDropList
         [cdkDropListData]="interventionsTodo" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dragContainer">
      <div class="dragInter" *ngFor="let i of interventionsTodo" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      <a class="resetInv" (click)="reset()"><div class="dragInter"><img src="../assets/images/simulation-intervention/noIntervention.svg" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div></a><!---->
    </div>

    <div class="dropContainer">
      <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDoneNow" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDoneNow" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      </div>
        <div class="connectorL"></div>
      <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDonePlus5" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDonePlus5" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="connectorL"></div>
      <div cdkDropList  [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDonePlus10" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDonePlus10" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="connectorL"></div>
      <div cdkDropList  [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDonePlus15" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDonePlus15" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="connectorL"></div>
      <div cdkDropList  [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDonePlus20" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDonePlus20" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="connectorL"></div>
      <div cdkDropList  [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDonePlus25" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDonePlus25" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="connectorL"></div>
      <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="interventionsDonePlus30" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="dropZone">
        <div class="dragInterDropped" *ngFor="let i of interventionsDonePlus30" cdkDrag><img src="{{i.imgSrc}}" class="interventionIc" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

All fine, now i have the cdkDropListDroppet event which calls the function `drop()`

```
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<{ imgSrc: string }[], any>) {
     if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
       moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
     } else {
         if(event.container.data === this.interventionsTodo){
         this.deleteSpecificItemFromTimeline(event.previousContainer.data[0]);
         }else if(event.container.data.length <1){
           copyArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
             event.container.data,
             event.previousIndex,
             event.currentIndex);
         }
      }
    }
```

this works fine, now im unit testing the angular app (jasmine/karma)
and i am trying to dispatch the CdkDragDrop event so that i can verify the functionality of my `drop()` function.

So in the angular documentation there is a small chapter on component DOM testing, where its mentioned that you have to get the htmlElement where you want to fire the event which i do like this:[angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing)

```
    let Dbg = fixture.debugElement;
    let htE = Dbg.nativeElement.querySelector(".dragContainer");
```

now i have the element on which i want to fire the event so full code looks like this

```
    let Dbg = fixture.debugElement;
      let htE = Dbg.nativeElement.querySelector(".dragContainer");

      htE.addEventListener('CdkDragDrop', (ev:any) => {
        component.drop(ev);
      });
      let bla = htE.dispatchEvent(new Event('cdkDropListDropped'));
```

So bla returns true, which (if im not wrong) means the event was fired, but nothing seems to happen
`fixture.detectchanges()` happens automatically..
i tried to debug it to see what is happening but the listenerfunction is never fired and i looked everywhere to find an answer but cant seem to find anything on that kind of eventtesting..

Comment: One great initial resource for unit test examples are the tests located in library's source code: https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/cdk/drag-drop

Comment: Hi, are you able to find the solution? I have encountered the similar situation in my unit test now.

Comment: Hei Jun, so the link Alexander mentioned has a lot of examples on how to test CdkDragDrop.. but the problem here is with Angular, so if you check the tests in the repo given by Alex, you will mostly find some imports around @angular/core/testing .. and the problem here is that this testing module is not publicly available, due to not beeing properly formated and commented and whatnot. So, as for the moment you cannot really test your Stuff.. atleast thats what i learned, i hope this helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to fire events from your template, you could test your `drop` method with some mocked events. I'm doing so by using a generic [DragDropEventFactory](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/test/drag-drop-event-factory.ts).

[summary-table-side-bar.component.spec.ts](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/summary-table-side-bar/summary-table-side-bar.component.spec.ts) illustrates how corresponding unit tests may look like.

Comment: any stackblitz link for unit testing of cdk drag drop feature?